# Best way to get Python script as an executable file?

Tags: python, c++

I'm creating an application using Python 3.4.3 and tkinter for a project as this is the language I am strongest and most fluent in. However, for the specification it would make much more sense for the end user to have a compiled application to run. Is there any way to either compile Python (pretty sure there isn't) or a way to get C++, or any other compiled language, to run a Python script? Quite a broad question (sorry) and any hints and tips would be useful.

Comment: Yes it's possible for a C++ program to call a python script. Easiest way would be to use `popen()`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962430/calling-python-script-from-c-and-using-its-output.

Comment: If the only goal is to make the python code into an executable you could use something like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: You can also embed Python interpreter if needed, look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

Comment: Also one other thing you might consider is turning the problem on it's head: you can make your c++ code exposed as a python API using something like [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that what you want is to end with a single (Windows ?) executable that you could send to your end users to ease deployment.

It is possible (and easy) for scripts that only use a limited and know set of modules, there is even a nice tool on SourceForge dedicated to it: [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (following is extracted from tutorial).

You just prepare a `setup.py` script (when original script is trivially simple with a command line UI):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['myscript.py'])
```

and run `python setup.py py2exe`

As soon as you are using a GUI and many modules, things can become harder, even if doc lets think that tkinter seems correctly processed.

Comment: I'm sorry that this is just hints, but py2exe generally needs configuration and that configuration depends on what modules the python script uses.

Comment: Indeed `pyinstaller` or `py2exe` are very good ways to start; There's no C++ code to write, not sure if that's what OP is asking, but runtime can be accessed just as well.

Answer (score 2):

What I've done in the past is to use the Python C API to load a Python module, call some methods, and convert values back into C types.  See the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3.4//c-api/index.html

I can't give detailed information here (read the docs), but here is a really basic example (I'm doing this off the top of my head,  so there may be problems in my example, and it omits all error checking)

```
// first you would have to load the module
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *module = PyImport_ImportModule(module_name);

// you would want to do some error checking to make sure the module was actually loaded

// load the module dictionary
PyObject *module_dict = PyModule_GetDict(module);

// call the constructor to create an instance
PyObject *constructor = PyDict_GetItemString(module_dict, "ClassName");
PyObject *instance = PyObject_CallObject(constructor, NULL);
Py_DECREF(constructor);

// call a method that takes two integer arguments
PyObject *result = PyObject_CallMethod(instance, "method_name", "ii", 5, 10);

// let's pretend the result is an integer
long log_val = PyInt_AsLong(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Nuitka](http://nuitka.net/pages/overview.html) and it really works like a charm.
Nuitka translates python code to C++ and compile it, creating an executable. You can tell Nuitka what part of python code must be compiled: only your code, your code and some libraries, or everything, including linking with the python interpreter to get a stand alone executable.

[Cython](http://cython.org) works great too (although  I experimented some problema when using de `super` function in derived clases). In this case you need the interpreter.