# Run python object in C++

Tags: python, c++

I just have a question about running a python object in C++.  Let me explain what I want to do in the following example.

```
int main () {
    // as you know, the python object has its member variables etc, and 
    // I want it to be initialized only once
    py = python_object();   
    while (1) {
        // here, I am hoping to call a member function from the object continously
        // and get a return value. 
        int abc = py.get_num(); 
        if (abc < 0) break;
        do_something_in_my_cpp_code();
    }


}
```

---

The python object that I was talking about this here [Capture oOjbect](https://github.com/alexa-pi/AlexaPi/blob/master/src/alexapi/capture.py).

I am wondering how difficult would this be, if you guys have any experience of dealing with things like this.  I am also open to other possible methods, such as the reverse (running a C++ object inside a python script).Thanks!

Comment: Of course it is *possible*. The *real* question is how much effort it will take..

Comment: Yes, this is what I am asking really. I am wondering how difficult would that be?

Comment: Then why didn't you ask *that* question?   The obvious response to "is it possible" is "yes" - and then we move on. Ask the *real* question.

Comment: As a comment: the reverse way is easy using SWIG. (Calling C++ Objects from Python). That way you are also using the power of both languages correctly. What you are planning is prob possible but much harder.

Comment: @lalala, the reverse way also works for me. I am wondering how difficult would that be?

Comment: @JesperJuhl, let me re-frame my question, sorry about that

Comment: You should read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962430/calling-python-script-from-c-and-using-its-output#16963206

Comment: Not difficult. Check out this here: http://realmike.org/blog/2010/07/18/python-extensions-in-cpp-using-swig/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution 1**
create a small python  script that calls your function and prints the result.
then , in the c++ program use popen to call the python  script and retrieve the displayed value.

**solution 2**
embed python in your c++ program
https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html

if you have only very few python calls, I think solution 1 is the faster and safer way.