# Running a C++ code and a Python code consecutively

Tags: python, c++, linux

I know it's a very general question but I am open for different options.

Let me clarify what my codes do:

- The C++ code produces multiple .png files as output as follows

  ./Debug/mycpp input1path input2path output parameter1 parameter2
- The python code takes those png files to do image processing and returns them as png as well

  mypython.py inputpath outputpath

What I want to do:
* To create an "executor code" that runs and links those 2 codes
* The only criterion is that 'the executor code' should work on Ubuntu

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**Additional notes:**
* I don't want to call c++ in python, I just want to create a 3rd code (e.g. shell script) that calls c++ first then calls python after c++ has finished it's task.

Comment: So .. a simple shell script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling Python script from C++ and using its output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962430/calling-python-script-from-c-and-using-its-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is perfect for such scripts, it has a complete support for such scripts.

You should look at `subprocess` and `os` modules for the complete command set for it.

Comment: Many thanks. Indeed, I used os library and it was extremely easy to use.

Comment: @uguros Python is classic for that matter as it was designed as a scripting languague

Answer (score 0):

Compile the `c++scipt.cpp` to an executable `c++script`. Then add the following in a shell script (`script.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
./c++script
python pythonscript.py
```

Then run with

```
$ sh script.sh
```

or (the first command just makes it executable)

```
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh
```

Comment: Many thanks. I used Python's "os library" in Python so that I can run my C++ code in the Python itself.