# Implementation of generalized hypergeometric function pFq

Tags: c++, c, numerical-methods

Is there an implementation callable from C or C++ that allows the evaluation of the [generalized hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function) `pFq(a1,...,ap; b1,...,bp; x)`?

I tried GSL and Boost, but I don't think the generalized function is available in either of those libraries.

Comment: Did you manage to find a valid C version of that function? I'm still relying on the mpmath with python but I would like to have it in C!
It seems very difficult to implement the `hypergeometric` module of mpmath in C!

Comment: @linello Nothing. Now I am also in need of [Kummer's confluent for complex arguments](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/20927/988), which doesn't appear to have a C/C++ implementation either. If you find any let me know!

Answer (score 5):

I believe the [Arb](http://fredrikj.net/arb/index.html) library, a C library for arbitrary-precision floating-point ball arithmetic developed by the creator of mpmath, now [provides an implementation](http://fredrikj.net/arb/acb_hypgeom.html).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using this [python library](https://mpmath.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/build/functions/hypergeometric.html) for the functions you need. It seems like it has it.

The trick however is you need to be able to call a python script from C++. For that you can use a [boost component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137/calling-python-from-a-c-program-for-distribution).

This seems like the easiest solution, even if it is possibly inefficient.