# use the return value of a python function through a c++ script

Tags: python, c++

I would like to call a  python function through  a c++ script. I know how to call a c++ function in a python code but no the other way. for example, I would like to use the return value of this python function in a c++ script like this:

```
import pandas as pd
def concat(x1,x2):
a = pd.DataFrame(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x1), pd.DataFrame(x2)], axis=1))
return a
```

#

```
void Foot::update(){
ccerr << "Merge " << PLate->me->vertIncl << endl;
con[a] = concat(model->getA(),model->getB())}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You will have to use system to run the python file and then parse the output. Will be good for scripts. But calling a function of the script not sure about that.

Comment: What about RFC or pipe/socket remote calls?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137/calling-python-from-a-c-program-for-distribution have a look here

Comment: I read it before Kishan Kumar, but i didn't find my answer, because what i really want is the return value of the python function. thank you for the answer

Comment: @JennyRolande: This (answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/328451/3545273) in the proposed duplicate contains all what you need. You have to embed (or link) both the Python interpretor **and** the pandas library in your C++ program.

Comment: @SergeBallesta ah ok. thank you so much. I will try it immediately