# Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec & ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, c++, embed

### Intention

I want to access a python function from C++ and am using C++17 and Python 3.7.3.

### My Visual Studio Project settings

- C/C++ > General > Additional include directories > "D:\Programme\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\python3.6"
- Linker > General > Additional library directories > "D:\Programme\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib"
- Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > python36.lib;...

### Main.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "tchar.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    printf("Calling Python to find the sum of 2 and 2.\n");

    // Initialize the Python interpreter.
    Py_Initialize();

    // Create some Python objects that will later be assigned values.
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;

    // Convert the file name to a Python string.
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString("Sample");

    // Import the file as a Python module.
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

    // Create a dictionary for the contents of the module.
    pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

    // Get the add method from the dictionary.
    pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "add");

    // Create a Python tuple to hold the arguments to the method.
    pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);

    // Convert 2 to a Python integer.
    pValue = PyLong_FromLong(2);

    // Set the Python int as the first and second arguments to the method.
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pValue);

    // Call the function with the arguments.
    PyObject* pResult = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    // Print a message if calling the method failed.
    if (pResult == NULL)
        printf("Calling the add method failed.\n");

    // Convert the result to a long from a Python object.
    long result = PyLong_AsLong(pResult);

    // Destroy the Python interpreter.
    Py_Finalize();

    // Print the result.
    printf("The result is %d.\n", result); std::cin.ignore(); return 0;
}
```

### Sample.py

```
# Returns the sum of two numbers.
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

### My directories

[directory of files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1M4f.png)

[release version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC3eQ.png)

[solution directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v73OX.png)

### The error

```
Calling Python to find the sum of 2 and 2.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003ca0 (most recent call first):
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49137/1757964

Comment: @APerson I will check out this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution from @Calvin1602 (a Stackoverflow user) from this post [Py_Initialize fails - unable to load the file system codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694706/py-initialize-fails-unable-to-load-the-file-system-codec)

> I just ran into the exact same problem (same Python version, OS, code, etc).
>
> You just have to copy Python's Lib/ directory in your program's
>   working directory ( on VC it's the directory where the .vcproj is )