# How to communicate from OMNeT++ with AI agent written in Python during runtime?

Tags: python, machine-learning, omnet++

I have a simulator written in OMNeT++ V. 4.6. I am using INET framework to use the features I want in OMNeT++. During runtime, the simulator needs to send some data to an AI agent that is written in Python. The data are the average SNR of the links in the network along with the location of the mobile nodes in the network. Then, the agent is trained by the newly received data in an online fashion.

The AI agent receives the data and generates the required actuation to keep the SNR maximum in the network. The actuation that is generated by the agent in Python needs to be sent over to the simulator in OMNeT++. I want to know how this can be done in run time for the two processes in Python and OMNeT++.

Answer (score 0):

`OMNeT++` uses C++, so you can use any way available in C++ for calling a method from Python, for example mentioned here: [Calling python from a c++ program for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137/calling-python-from-a-c-program-for-distribution)